VS Code Remote-SSH: What is the difference between `ssh -T -D` and `ssh -T -L` connections
I'm trying to debug why a colleague can't make a Remote-SSH connection with VS Code. They get this error:

Could not establish connection to "remote.host.name": Error establishing tunnel (Max wait time exhausted).

I think it might have to do with the ssh command arguments.
My successful connection has this in the OUTPUT: Remote-SSH

Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 58304 "remote.host.name" bash

But their connection uses the arguments
ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:53514:/path/on/remote/code-0ae38beb-47d3-4a9e-9ffc-abe760af43b4 "remote.host.name" bash

My question isn't necessarily why the connection fails, but my question is why and when does VS Code Remote-SSH use the argument -D versus -L and what is the difference?

-D is very similar to -L.  -L forwards any port, but with -D, the port number is determined on the fly based on the protocol used to connect.  Only SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 are supported.
